# Can I use a backbone app as a component in another app?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm still getting familiar to Backbone.js and front-end development (I'm more focused on back-end development) and I have a question regarding to composition.

Let's say I need to create a reusable component, such as RichText editor, which can later be used in other places inside my app, but also be reusable in other apps either.

Is that a way to conduce development in Backbone such as this? Or is it not meant for this kind o usage?

**Edit:** I'm reading about the use of Backbone combined with React. Maybe this is the path I should take. I'll dig more on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a backbone view, model or collection reusable but you'll have to reinsert it in a context where backbone is used.
Backbone is useful to build small independent views and render composition of those.

```
MainView
    SearchContainerView
    SubscribeView
    ContentView
    ...
```

You can also you react to build reusable component it's also a great tool for composition. The update mechanism in react is a little bit easier than backbone, I suggest you use the Flux pattern if you decide to use React.

Comment: I'm trying to understand Flux and how it can help me... be it by replacing Backbone, be it to be plugged between the backbone and react (I'm reading some people describing what they're calling 'Backbone Stores'). It seems a lot interesting... I'll dig more into it.
Thanks.